# Bayesian fitting with very noisy data

Tags: bayesian, fitting, pymc

I am trying to fit a response curve through noisy data. The curve is supposed to model a saturating return, which takes the analytical form:

$$ x \to y(x) = \alpha( 1- e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}})$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the unknowns, to which we assign normal priors.

I am using PyMC3 to sample the prior. The model is:

$$
\alpha \propto N(a,b)\\
\beta  \propto N(c,d)\\
 \varepsilon \propto N(0, \sigma)\\
y(x) = \alpha( 1- e^{-\frac{x}{\beta}}) + \varepsilon
$$

This is the output I get from the posterior sampling:

[image]

I am unhappy with the fact that most data points are not in the 50% confidence band. In my mind, more points (~50%) should fall inside this area.

I have played with the parameters $a,b,c,d,\sigma$ with little effect. I am suspecting that the model is wrong. Precisely the culprit could be the distribution I assume for $\varepsilon$, the departure.

I am running out of ideas to debug this. What can I try?

As asked this is my model:

```py
(mle_alpha, mle_beta), (mle_alpha_unc, mle_beta_unc) = robust_clean_curve_fit(func, x, y_obs )
mle_alpha_unc = min(mle_alpha_unc, 1e5)
mle_beta_unc = min(mle_beta_unc, 1e5)
obs_std = (func( x, mle_alpha, mle_beta) - y_obs).std()

pessimism_factor = 1e2 #5.
n_samples = int(1e4)
tune_steps = int(1e5)
confidence_quartile = 0.5

with pm.Model() as mod:
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mle_alpha, mle_alpha_unc*pessimism_factor)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mle_beta, mle_beta_unc*pessimism_factor, )
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', sd=obs_std*pessimism_factor) #sd better be too high than too low!!
    y = alpha * ( 1. - tt.exp(-x/beta))
    Y_obs = pm.Normal('Y_obs', mu=y, sigma=sigma, observed=y_obs)


    step = pm.NUTS()
    trace = pm.sample( n_samples, step, tune=tune_steps, chains=12, cores=12)
    summary_df = pm.summary( trace, var_names=['alpha','beta'], alpha=1-confidence_quartile)
```

FYI `robust_clean_curve_fit` returns the MLE fitted parameters and rough uncertainties evaluated on the numerical Hessian matrix + chi2 of the fit.

Comment: "I am unhappy with the fact that most data points are not in the 50% confidence band. In my mind, more points (~50%) should fall inside this area" -- That isn't how the credible interval works.  It would be more reasonable to make this statement about the posterior predictive interval.  Can we see your model statement?

Comment: I know it is not how confidence translates but in this case, I am trying to model some risk ($x$ is a spend and $y$ is a return), so I need a confidence on where the observations can fall. I am wondering if the strong non-linearity of the model is the culprit.

Comment: Non-linearity is not the culprit.  If the interval you've plotted is the credible interval for y conditioned on x, then having 50% of observations in the interval would mean your system has little noise.  Plot the posterior predictive interval instead and see what you think of the results.

Comment: I am not sure what is the posterior predictive interval, how does it relate to the posteriors on $\alpha, \beta$.

Comment: Posterior predictive draws generate data you would see tomorrow if you captured data from the same process which generated the data you already have.  I can't enough about them in a comment, but I highly suspect you want the PPI.  Bayesian Data Analysis by Gelman and colleagues has a very good section on PPI in chapter 6.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resource and the feedback. Will have a look and try to clarify my question if still needs be.